# Canopen Position Control Without Mode 7

Tags: control, ros, position

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to control my own robot arm using moveit by canopen protocol, but my driver is not supported to use interpolate position mode, which is mode 7. It only has profiled position mode, profiled velocity mode, so how can I still use moveit to control my robot by these two mode?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280362/canopen-position-control-without-mode-7/) by [leo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33187/leo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2018-01-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes Leo, some of the drives doesn't support all the motion control modes.  I am not well aware of Canopen protocol, But I am working on Ethercat protocol which is based on Canopen. Based on that knowledge I can suggest you that, using SDO communication you can set the drive to Profile Position/Velocity mode after that you need to use PDOs to send cyclic velocity or position values to update to the slave from master controller. But, these modes directly can't create any motion to your hardware for that you have to keep track on Status word and send appropriate Control word and then position/velocity update. If you can mention which  motion control drive you are using I can suggest you which algorithm you have to follow?

---

Originally posted by [TraiBo](https://answers.ros.org/users/28181/traibo/) with karma: 146 on 2018-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rhnbmpl](https://answers.ros.org/users/30793/rhnbmpl/) on 2018-02-01**:
Yeah, it worked perfectly for me. Can you share any documentation related to the algorithm?